# SDL and C++11 threads

Tags: multithreading, c++11, sdl

I'm developing an application in C++11 which uses SDL as a library. I'm planning to add multithreaded support for my app. Is there any difference whether to use SDL_Thread or std::thread in my application?

Comment: Depending on chosen implementation, SDL can use C++ threads, as well as target system specific implementation like pthreads. If specifics are that important to your problem, you surely should look at what both SDL and C++ does. SDL probably provides finer control over e.g. thread stack size (*if* it isn't using C++ threads as its threads implementation).

Answer (score 4):

Unless you're using a part of the SDL API that specifically requires SDL's thread handle type, you're better off using C++'s `std::thread`. The API is more idiomatic (e.g. the constructor allowing you to forward arguments to start function) and does not tie that code to what SDL provides.

The reason I mention the handle is if you actually need to pass an `SDL_Thread *`, there is no way to query for handle to the current thread. Granted `std::thread` does not provide this either, but since the interface is richer, it makes more sense to use.

Edit: Both interfaces seem to draw heavily from POSIX threads, but with one exception. `std::thread` does not have a built-in cancellation function. Normally, you don't want to kill a thread anyway without any sort of cleanup, but it is worth mentioning.